# How do I make Cucumber and RMagick play nice on Snow Leopard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, osx-snow-leopard, cucumber

I installed Snow Leopard and things have been going great, after a few re-installs. But now when I go to run cucumber, I get the error below, and I can't find anything conclusive through Google searches. Has anyone run into this, or maybe have some troubleshooting steps to try?

```
$ cucumber features 
dyld: NSLinkModule() error
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.10.0/lib/RMagick2.bundle
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /opt/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib: can't map
    /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
Trace/BPT trap
```

Comment: That's probably just another 32/64 bit problem ("wrong architecture"), at least if the output of "file /opt/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib" isn't anything out of the extraordinary. Recompile your binaries and make sure they match your running kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if rmagick is the correct version and compiled correctly for your new osx.

Answer (score 0):

It resulted that the .dylib file was in **/usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib**

so it was just matter of copying it from there, or make a symbolic link:

```
cd /opt/local/lib/
ln -s /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
```